# Plotting a kidney shape in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, anatomy

How can a kidney shape be plotted in Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 9):

You can plot a [bean curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4239811/area-enclosed-by-bean-curve) as presented in the link.

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[c (x^2 + y^2)^2 == a x^3 + b y^3
  , {x, -0.5, 1.25}, {y, -0.5, 1.25}
  , ContourStyle -> Red
  , PlotPoints -> 50
  ]
 , {{a, 1}, 0.5, 1.5}
 , {{b, 1}, 0.5, 1.5}
 , {{c, 1}, 0.5, 1.5}
 ]
```

[image]

---

Mathematica has a fully featured `AnatomyPlot3D` command that can display anatomically accurate 3D primitives. The resultant 3D images can be rotated in space.

[image]

Comment: You can also try: `AnatomyPlot3D[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "UrinarySystem"]]`